# How can I check when was a docker image pulled?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-registry

I want to know when I pulled a certain image, when you run `docker images` The Created field appear but the date that the image was pulled don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you installed `docker-engine` from official repositories on your linux, it should be installed in `/var/lib/docker`, for your own configuration, find the respective path.

There is `/var/lib/docker/image/aufs/repositories.json` file where docker stores images with their `sha256` values.

```
cat /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/repositories.json
```

Find the image you are looking after and copy its `sha256` hash somewhere.

Then:

```
ls /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/imagedb/content/sha256 -lash
```

Find the `sha265` value you found in `repositories.json` then look at the date.

Comment: It's more convenient to use `docker images | grep <IMAGE NAME>` to find the image's sha256 value and then `ls -l /var/lib/docker/image/<GRAPH DRIVER>/imagedb/content/sha256 | grep <sha256 value>` .